# pytorch backports.functools_lru_cache conflict

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch

I'm using *Windows 10*, and my the installation dir is:
`anacoda2/python2.7/python3.6/opencv/cdua10/cudnn ....`

Now I want to install pytorch, with this command: `conda install pytorch -c pytorch`

But as result I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\MM>conda install pytorch -c pytorch
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports.functools_lru_cache
  - pytorch
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

The version of `backports.functools_lru_cache` is `1.4`.

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while installing pytorch. I was able to resolve it by
creating another environment on anaconda which had python version 3.6.